# our Site`s CKEditor, disappears in one specific browser with errors in console

Tags: ckeditor4.x

We developed an ASP.NET Web From site and used CKEditor 4.18.0 in many pages.
The CKEditor is working very well, but the disappears on only one of our Windows 10 client and only in it's Chrome browser (Firefox is working well), I saw some errors in it`s Chrome Console:

```
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:16     GET https://transnet.ir/ckeditor/plugins/n/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:16     GET https://transnet.ir/ckeditor/plugins/o/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:16     GET https://transnet.ir/ckeditor/plugins/t/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:16     GET https://transnet.ir/ckeditor/plugins/i/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:16     GET https://transnet.ir/ckeditor/plugins/c/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:16     GET https://transnet.ir/ckeditor/plugins/a/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
ckeditor.js?t=C6HH5UF:23 Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "n,n" was not found at "https://transnet.ir/Qualifier/../ckeditor/plugins/n/plugin.js?t=B8DJ5M3".
```

There is no especial plugin in this Chrome browser installation.
In our Web site project There is another folder of CKEditor with another version (4.5.6) and I am suspicious there most be some confusion between these 2 folders but I cannot prove it yet. til then, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It fixed with ordinary Windows maintenance job like cleaning Windows's registry and cleaning Chrome's cache, cleaning Windows's temp & junk file and restarting Windows.